# Uniqueness of Inverse

Tags: matrices, inverse

I am having trouble understanding the logic for a few steps in the following. I'll point the steps out at the end.

If B and C are inverses of a square matrix A, then B = C.

Proof: Since B is an inverse of A, we have
BA = I and AB = I.

Also, since C is an inverse of A, we have 
CA = I and AC = I.

So AB = I $\implies$ CAB = CI $\implies$ IB = C $\implies$ B = C.

So my confusions is in the last set of steps. How do we get from:

CAB = CI $\implies$ IB = C

And

IB = C $\implies$ B =C

The above steps are not obvious to me.

Also why is the proof not:

CA = I  $\implies$ CA = BA, and by cancelation of matrices we have C = B?

Comment: Your simple proof doesn't have much detail because cancelation law is not clear. It should be CAC = BAC $\iff$ CI = BI $\iff$ C = B

Comment: If I is an identity then Ix = xI =x for all square matrices.  So CAB = C(AB) = CI = C.  But CAB = (CA)B = IB = B.  SO C = CAB = B.  You can do cancelation but the other proof is simpler and more straightforward.  But they are the exact same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have $AB=I$, then multiply for the left side of this equation for $C$ you have:
$$C(AB)=CI$$
for the property associative of multiplication of matrix we  have $C(AB)=(CA)B$,we
 know that too $CI=C$ and $CA=I$
$$(CA)B=CI<=>IB=C<=>B=C$$

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the fact that $IB = B$ and $CI = C$.

Comment: you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

Your simple proof just needs a little more justification.  To expand upon your proof, you can say

> Since $CA=I=BA$, we have $CAB=BAB$, which simplifies to $C=B$.

Comment: Hi and thank you for your response. Can you elaborate on why we had to add $B$ and what you meant by "justification".

Comment: It is somewhat of an unnecessary step, it just helps the reader understand that _you_ know what is going on.  Cancellation of matrices, as you claimed to be your reasoning for removing $A$ from both sides of the equation $CA=BA$, is only valid if $A$ is invertible.  This is certainly true under the current hypotheses, but it is not true for general matrices, hence I recommend you add the additional equation.

Comment: And by justification, I meant that your argument should follow from what you have stated.  This mostly stems from your usage of the term "cancellation of matrices", which I elaborated on above.  This terminology is, to some extent, ambiguous, and may lead to some questioning as to whether or not you understand what you are claiming.